# Missing number on newenvironment with tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I have the following code to resize a `tikzpicture` only in case it's too wide:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{environ}

\newsavebox\mybox
\newenvironment{resizedtikzpicture}[1]{%
    \def\mywidth{#1}%
    \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
}{%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{lrbox}%
    \if\wd\mybox>\mywidth
        \resizebox{\mywidth}{!}{\usebox\mybox}%
    \else
        \usebox\mybox %
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
\begin{resizedtikzpicture}{\textwidth}
\end{resizedtikzpicture} % line 69
\end{document}
```

but it's giving me the following error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \unhbox 
l.69             \end{resizedtikzpicture}
```

I don't understand where that `unhbox` is coming from. How can I fix this error? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please edit the fragments to be a small self contained document that reproduces the error (not relying on external links)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    \if\wd\mybox>\mywidth
```

should be

```
    \ifdim\wd\mybox>\mywidth
```